# Running external scripts in Python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, powershell, subprocess

I'm trying to run a PowerShell script using `subprocess.call` and not having much luck.

```
subprocess.call(['.\ConvertPPTtoImage.ps1', path+'file.pptx'])
```

Running `.\ConvertPPTtoImage.ps1 file.pptx` directly from PowerShell works fine, but the above line just opens `ConvertPPTtoImage.ps1`in Notepad. I've tried other variations (removing the `.\` from the start, removing the `shell=True`, using os.system instead of subprocess.call) and got crashes or `WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the PowerShell executable itself. By default, Windows will open `.ps1` files in Notepad, or another text editor of your choosing. They don't run using PowerShell by default, as a security feature.

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File c:\path\to\ConvertPPTtoImage.ps1 c:\path\to\file.pptx
```

Answer (score 0):

Working primarily on linux machines, this would be my best guess.  It sounds like `ConvertPPTtoImage.ps1` is a script which is then run by powershell.  The command is attempting to run it either (a) using the default program for `ps1` files, which would open it in Notepad, or (b) as an executable in itself, which fails because a text file is not itself executable.  The solution would be to replace the call as follows.

```
subprocess.call([r'C:\path\to\powershell.exe',r'.\ConvertPPTtoImage.ps1',path+'file.pptx'])
```

That is, calling powershell with an argument to tell it which script to run.

As a side note, whenever working with Windows paths in python, I would recommend putting an r before the start of each string, which tells python to ignore escape sequences.  Since python's escape character and Window's path delimiter are both backslashes, this saves a lot of headaches down the line.